Why do I get duplicate collected pytest anyio tests
Context
I am writing tests for my MongoDB + FastAPI backend using pytest and asyncio. I faced many different issues while setting it up such as Event Loop Close, Task Pending <name=, and AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'post'. But I ended up with this setup that works. So here is a minimum reproducible example. I apologize for it being so long, but I think it is necessary to know the entire context
Project Setup
main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from app.database import close_mongo_connection, connect_to_mongo
from app.routes.auth_routes import router as auth_router
app = FastAPI()

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    print("Connecting to MongoDB")
    await connect_to_mongo()
    yield
    print("Closing connection to MongoDB")
    await close_mongo_connection()

app.router.lifespan_context = lifespan

app.include_router(auth_router, prefix="/auth", tags=["auth"])

database.py:
import os
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from app.config import DATABASE_NAME, MONGO_DETAILS, TEST_DATABASE_NAME

client: AsyncIOMotorClient = None
db = None

async def connect_to_mongo():
    global client, db
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient(MONGO_DETAILS)
    if os.getenv("IS_TESTING") == "True":
        db = client[TEST_DATABASE_NAME]
    else:
        db = client[DATABASE_NAME]

async def close_mongo_connection():
    if os.getenv("IS_TESTING") == "True":
        await client.drop_database(TEST_DATABASE_NAME)
    client.close()
    print("Disconnected from MongoDB")

async def get_database():
    if db is None:
        await connect_to_mongo()
    return db

routes/auth_routes:
from app.database import get_database
from fastapi import APIRouter
router = APIRouter()

async def create_user(user: UserCreate, db) -> UserModel:
    users_collection = db["users"]
    user_dict = user.model_dump()
    user_dict["hashed_password"] = get_password_hash(user_dict.pop("password"))
    return await users_collection.insert_one(user_dict)

@router.post("/register", response_model=UserModel)
async def register_user(user: UserCreate, db=Depends(get_database)):
    print("GET DB", db)
    db_user = await create_user(user, db)
    return db_user

(Relevant) Installed Libraries:
anyio             4.4.0
httpcore          1.0.5
httptools         0.6.1
httpx             0.27.0
motor             3.4.0
pip               24.0
pytest            8.2.2
pytest-asyncio    0.23.7
python-dotenv     1.0.1

Testing Setup
tests/conftest.py:
import pytest
from app.database import close_mongo_connection, connect_to_mongo

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
async def setup_and_teardown():
    await connect_to_mongo()
    print("This function does not run, but the testing setup does not work without it")
    yield
    await close_mongo_connection()

tests/test_auth.py:
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient, ASGITransport
from app.main import app
from app.database import connect_to_mongo, close_mongo_connection

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
async def setup_and_teardown():
    await connect_to_mongo()
    print("this runs")
    yield
    await close_mongo_connection()

client = AsyncClient(transport=ASGITransport(app=app), base_url="http://testserver")

@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_register_user():
    user_data = {
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "password": "password123",
    }
    response = await client.post("/auth/register", json=user_data)

Problem
The functionality is fine, the tests behave correctly. But whenever I type the pytest command, double the number of tests is collected. For instance, in the setup I provided example, pytest would collect 2 tests and they would both execute (could be verified by seeing that 2 users are created). This applies to all tests in multiple files. In my full setup I have 6 tests, but it always collects and executes 12 tests. Why does that happen and how can I fix it.

what is the output when you type:
pytest --collect-only

@volkan Double the number of the actual tests. So in the sample code, it would give 2, even though I only have 1 test

I see that it is double but by running collect-only, you can check Directory, Package and Module names that tests are collected from to have better understanding where they comes from. If they are identical, you can check if you somehow import test_auth.py to another module.

@volkan, the same test name is collected twice, but within brackets, one is [asyncio] and the other is [trio], I have tried to uninstall trio or mess with the pytest.ini file to force one of the backends, but it didn't work. The tests kept getting doubled

Seeing the same test with square brackets indicates that pytest is parameterizing your test. I recommend checking if your test method or the conftest.py file is set up to parameterize your tests with asyncio and trio

@volkan, the full conftest.py and the test setup are included in the question, I don't have anything extra

I think this will solve your problem:
@pytest.fixture
def anyio_backend():
    return 'asyncio'

I took it from the official documentation,
By this way the AnyIO make tests only with asyncio.
